# Check if login details are correct for a user in a SQL database using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, ado.net

I have a C# MVC4 internet application and would like to check if login details are correct for a user.

I wish to do this from a Forms application using ADO.NET.

Here is the MVC code for a login:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Once connected to the SQL database, what SQL code do I need to use as a query to check if a password is correct for a user?

I would like to make a stored procedure if possible, but need to work out the SQL query string code.

How can I check login details for a SQL database user that has been created using the MVC application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use WebSecurity.Login`.

Comment: What SQL code can I use to do this?

Comment: You can't; it computes salted hashes.

Comment: So it is not possible to check the login details for a user using a SQL query?

Comment: No.  Also, you should never let your SQL DB see a plaintext password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `WebSecurity` without a custom `SimpleMembershipProvider` and your own user table, you can have `WebSecurity` [actually create some basic tables for you](http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp-net-webpages/) to keep track of user name, an MD5 hashed password, membership, and roles. From there in, its default implementation will connect to this database and find user information you request. You will need to do the following.

First, in your code -- I personally like to put this in `Global.asax.cs` -- you will need to connect it to the database schema where you want the user information to live like so...

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("[name of connection string]",
    "[users table name]",
    "[user id column name]",
    "[user name column name]",
    true);
```

That last `true` tells `WebSecurity` whether to create the user tables if they don't already exist or not. If you're not sure how it works, it may be beneficial to let it create these new tables which will be denoted with a `webpages_` prefix like so...

[image]

Then, to populate the user table with a new user, use the following...

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(userName, password);
```

This should get you more or less up and running, and give you enough to debug how the whole thing works so you can take advantage of the `WebSecurity` class features.

Comment: I have the following in the SimpleMembershipInitializer class: WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true); Is this what you are reffering to in your post?

Comment: Although note that [MD5 hashes for passwords are considered broken](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

Comment: Yes, @Clockwork-Muse MD5 hashes are useless for security. I usually recommend using salted BCrypt or PBKDF2 but since a) this doesn't exactly seem like a production app and b) the question is asking more or less for just the basics of dealing with the `WebSecurity` class, I wanted my response to be brief. Using a hashing algorithm other than MD5 here would require a custom membership provider implementation which is its own can of worms...

Comment: @user2985419, yes, this is the correct initializer. However, you can't use `DefaultConnection` as a valid argument. This must be the name of [a valid connection string in your `App.config` file](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/416198/How-to-get-Connection-String-from-App-Config-in-Cs). Otherwise it won't be able to connect unless you actually do have a connection string named `DefaultConnection` in your config file...